# Chrome DOM breakpoint keeps enabling itself

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Yes, in the console, I made the horrible mistake of setting a DOM breakpoint on an element that wasn't getting the content injected into it that I expected it to.

Well, now whenever I load that page, the breakpoint triggers. I uncheck the box next to it. It comes back. I right click on it and click "Remove Breakpoint." It disappears from the list, and seems to work fine until the next hard refresh, then BAM breakpoint.

I click the disable all breakpoints button. It once again works until the next refresh, then BAM breakpoint. Closed Chrome, reopened. Same. Closed all tabs individually and closed Chrome through the menu, wiping out all tab memory. Same.

```
I put on a loincloth and did an intricate dance,
I knew it was a stretch, but I gave it a chance.
I found an exorcist to help with my plight,
but he ran off promptly, screaming in fright.
With the light of Eärendil, my machine I did annoint,
hoping to rid it of this [expletive deleted] breakpoint.
But nothing has worked, no matter how hard I fought,
so now I humbly ask assistance of you lot.
```

Has anyone run into this issue?

I'm on Windows 7, Chrome 14.0.835.202 m.

Comment: I'm having the same problem! I have the same version and am running win 7. I'm dying over here

Comment: I am running into the same problem with Chrome 16.0.912.77 on OS X 10.7.2.

Comment: Please see possible cause here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10304499/51280

Answer (score 28, accepted):

solution here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91666

> To purge all breakpoints open inspector on inspector (undock first
> inspector and hit ctrl-shift-I to open the second) and run
> "WebInspector.settings.domBreakpoints.set([])" in second inspector's
> console.

**2021 Edit**: This answer is now a decade old, there are multiple alternatives in the comments to this answer. I haven't tested them, the most up to date is from @reuben-thompson: `window.localStorage.clear()`

Comment: I haven't tested this (too scared, to be honest) but because it is a solution aside from reintalling/upgrading chrome, I've marked it as the answer. If I ever run into this idiotic problem again, I'll try this in a second. Thanks!

Comment: I had non-dom breakpoints, so this didn't work BUT WebInspector.settings.breakpoints.set([]) did the trick (there were like 40 there) (well, it disabled them permanently anyways, they are still there somehow!!!)GRRR

Comment: I think this worked for me (I also did some other things, so I'm not positive) when I ran that command, then closed the tab and reopened it (didn't appear to work in the same tab session).

Comment: This is the only solution I've found for this that actually works.

Comment: Mac: Cmd + Option/Alt + I

Comment: Using Chrome 44 I'm getting the following error: WebInspector.settings.domBreakpoints.set([])
VM23876:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'domBreakpoints' of undefined

Comment: wierd, i did that, and i get what looks like an error `ReferenceError: WebInspector is not defined
 

WebInspector.settings.domBreakpoints.set([])

/* EXPR...set([]) (line 2)`, ran it with the quotes just to make sure,  then i ran m y code, again, and i now see what was formerly two invisble red breakpoints that were in teh exact location that the yellow triangle point it was topping at. This tells me that they were INVISIBLE, and this code snippet ran in console made visible again on first refresh (`WebInspector.settings.domBreakpoints.set([])`)

Comment: Chrome 45 - can't execute above. Used this instead: `WebInspector.settings._registry.get('domBreakpoints').set([])`

Comment: Got `ReferenceError: WebInspector is not defined`

Comment: same here, WebInspector is not defined... How do we do ?

Comment: On the latest version of Chrome `window.localStorage.clear()` did what we want (from inspecting the inspector)

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes when you set breakpoints you also autoenable "pause on exceptions". This will give unwanted persistant breakpointy behaviour. Cycle through the "pause on exceptions" button (bottom left) in order to switch it off (note- it is not on/off but three possible states)

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it, had to upgrade Chrome to 15.0.874.106.

```
Settings > About Google Chrome > Relaunch
```

My breakpoint is no longer triggering, but I am weary of testing whether the actual bug is fixed or not. No more DOM breakpoints in Chrome for me.

Comment: I don't think it's fixed. I added a breakpoint to an element that I can't remove. My Chrome is already up to date so I can't even do your little trick. Oh well.

Comment: I am running v *.121 and the bug is still there :-(

Comment: Still there in Chrome 23. Horrible.

Comment: My condolences, thanks for the update. I've successfully learned to live without this feature. What a nightmare.

Comment: Version 31 and just had to switch to another browser. Cannot get rid of the breakpoints. What is going on?

Comment: version 47 still the same! It creates temporary tabs for each js file, like `VM9514 global.js`, then after hitting `Remove all breakpoints`, they remain dimmed in the original file (`global.js` tab).

Answer (score 2):

I confirm that problem still exists in 2021. Deleting of Chrome user and adding it again helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem in Chrome 33. In the little inspector, in the section that window that has sub-windows for 'Breakpoints' & 'Call Stack', etc, at the top of the window is **a little book-mark icon that allows you to disable breakpoints.** New windows require you re-disable.

Not the best solution, but it has allowed me to keep working in Chrome for now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem still exists today and the accepted answer is from 7 years ago and no longer works.

Uninstalling and Reinstalling Chrome is the only way I could fix it.  See [Can't remove DOM breakpoint "subtree modification" in chrome 69.0.3497.100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52754131/cant-remove-dom-breakpoint-subtree-modification-in-chrome-69-0-3497-100/53549335#53549335)

It would be nice if Google would re-open the bug report mentioned above but they've permanently closed it even though it's not fixed.

Comment: Wow, crazy this is still an issue. I just stopped using DOM breakpoints altogether after I made this post and have never looked back.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear all your break points by opening the inspector inspector and typing `localStorage.breakpoints = ''`

Or if you'd like to manually decide which to keep you can use

```
InspectorFrontendHost.getPreferences(_ => window.mysnips = JSON.parse(_.scriptSnippets))
setTimeout(()=>{
    let snippetName = window.prompt("snippets name")||"BPs"+Math.random();

    let bps = JSON.parse(localStorage.breakpoints);
    let urls = [];
    let bpsToKeep = [];
    let bpsToSave = [];


    bps.forEach(bp=>{
        let alreadyProcessed = urls.filter(url=>url.url==bp.url)[0]
        if(!alreadyProcessed){
            alreadyProcessed = {url:bp.url};
            alreadyProcessed.save = confirm("save? : "+bp.url);

            urls.push(alreadyProcessed);
        }
        if(alreadyProcessed.save && !bp.enabled){
            bpsToSave.push(bp);
        }else{
            bpsToKeep.push(bp);
        }
    })

    window.mysnips.push({name:snippetName,content:""+JSON.stringify(bpsToSave)})
    InspectorFrontendHost.setPreference("scriptSnippets", JSON.stringify(window.mysnips))
    localStorage.breakpoints = JSON.stringify(bpsToKeep);
},300)
```

You can modify the script if you don't want to keep thos breakpoints as snippets.