# Chrome breaks randomly without breakpoints with the inspector open

Tags: macos, debugging, google-chrome

When I have the inspector open in chrome it will "break" all over the javascript even if there are no breakpoints. On sites that I need the debugger to debug javascript this makes chrome pretty unusable.

I'm on a mac, and I have tried deleting and reinstalling chrome. Anyone have any suggestions?

Gracias everyone!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could have had the "[Pause on all exceptions](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints#js_exceptions)" button enabled (it would be blue if enabled).

See screenshot below:

[image]

On Chrome 33.* you'll see it when viewing a script:

[image]

Comment: That's what it was on my system.  Thank you, thank you, thank you.  I had stopped using Chrome because I couldn't debug my sites without it stopping in jQuery repeatedly.  Chrome is back!

Comment: thanks - for this answer. had forgot that i had set this option. and btw this should be the accepted answer :-(

Comment: Though this is sometimes the cause, I frequently get random breaks while debugging JavaScript irregardless of the unhandled exception setting.

Comment: Do you know where to find that button on the latest version of Chrome? (that is `version 33.0.1750.117`)

Comment: this is doing this in v 46 with even the auto break button unticked

Answer (score 2):

I eventually resolved this by uninstalling chrome, removing this directory: ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/ (I'm on a mac) and reinstalling.  Not sure whether the deleting chrome step is really necessary.