# removing a breakpoint I didn't set

Tags: javascript

It seems to quite frequently happen that when I'm playing with code in the chrome console that execution of a webpage is stopped by a breakpoint in the jquery file, such as you see below. If I don't have the console open when running the page, it doesn't stop, only when console open.  I also can't click on the breakpoint to disable it. It also happens, in this instance and others, that when I'm trying to get access to the file with the custom javascript  it's not showing up in the sources presumably because things have stopped loading. I click the ||> arrow to push through the breakpoint, but the file with the javascript never loads in scripts, so I can't set breakpoints where I want.   Does what I've told you explain what I might be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I just had this problem last week.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528176/chrome-breaks-randomly-without-breakpoints-with-the-inspector-open

Answer (score 0):

You probably have Chrome set to pause on exceptions, which appears to be the default. Hover and/or click the little stopsign with pause symbol on the lower left of the dev tools Sources panel to change the setting.

Answer (score 0):

This could be from the line "debugger;" being in the code.  If this is the case there's no way to stop the break point other than removing the code.