# Can't remove DOM breakpoint "subtree modification" in chrome 69.0.3497.100

Tags: google-chrome, breakpoints

I've added a DOM breakpoint for "subtree modification" to the body element.
When I remove the DOM Breakpoint via "Remove breakpoint" or "Remove all DOM breakpoints" and reload the page the DOM breakpoint is there again.

Is there another way to remove the DOM breakpoints?

Just for the record: This happens only for "subtree modifications" breakpoints. "node removal" or "attribute modifications" work.

Answer (score 8):

One of our devs in the company had this same issue, We fixed it by going into chrome dev tools settings and restoring defaults.

Open Chrome dev tools, Press F1 the then just Restore Defaults. That seems to have fixed the issue for my colleague.

The F1 works on mac at least, If it docent work for you use the three dots menu in the upper right corner then settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem plaguing me for weeks.  None of the answers on SO are correct (the answers from 7 years ago are all invalid now since WebInspector doesn't exist).

The only way I was able to fix this was to uninstall and reinstall Chrome.  I know, this solution sucks but Google closed the bug 7 years ago and refuse to re-open it.  Yay Google.

Anyway, I can confirm reinstalling fixes it for me.